# query dynamodb function using gsi with more than 1MB of data

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to find a timely and cost-effective way to query a dynamodb table using a lambda function that will scan the table and return 1MB+ values using a sort key to determine which values to return. I read that parallel scans are a thing but since I have to use a sort key + GSI to narrow it down I'm not sure how much time that would save. I also saw that I could query the table into batches(by finding the LastEvaluatedKey) but considering that would be 10+ calls to the database every time(function is called every 10 mins) I don't think that would help as well!

If anyone has alternatives/advice it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Not really understanding your question or what you have in terms of primary partition/sort keys and GSIs. Perhaps you could elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear about what you are asking, but I'll highlight some of your options when fetching data from DynamoDB.  If this is not correct, can you elaborate on what you are asking or trying to do with DynamoDB?

Query and Scan operations are limited to 1MB response sizes before pagination.

The [BatchGetItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html) operation can retrieve up to 16 MB of data which can contain up to 100 items.  However, you'd need to know your items primary keys.  This doesn't sound like the case for you, since you are performing a `scan` operation.

Parallel scans can be beneficial in speeding up response time, but there are trade-offs.  [According to the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-query-scan.html), a parallel scan can be the right choice if the following conditions are met:

- The table size is 20 GB or larger.
- The table's provisioned read throughput is not being fully used.
- Sequential Scan operations are too slow.

If this sounds like your situation, you should look into using parallel scans.